# webpack (via Encore) compiles code successfully and then, many, many minutes later, throws an error

Tags: webpack, webpack-encore

Good morning

I'm running webpack (v5.74.0), via Symfony Encore (v3.0.0), using Yarn v1.22.17 on Node.js v14.18.0 -- I've tried v16.17.0 as well.

`yarn encore` apparently hangs after saying it's successfully compiled our JavaScript.  ++So it's likely there's a problem compiling our Sass.++  After a couple attempts, I just left it running and eventually it threw an error.  I don't know enough to understand what the stack trace is pointing at.  It looks as if the problem *could* be webpack but I can't find reference to the error code.  The error code doesn't appear to have anything to do with Yarn.  I wonder, have you seen this problem before?  Is there any way to see what webpack/Encore is doing?  I've read about, and tried, Encore's `--profile` CLI option but nothing new is displayed and I don't see a log file.  I'm not sure where to begin with this.  Any pointers will be very welcome, thank you.

Here's what I saw the last time I tried running Encore:

```bash
user@dan:~/vhtdocs/s/project$ yarn --verbose encore dev --profile
yarn run v1.22.17
verbose 0.648418183 Checking for configuration file "/home/user/vhtdocs/s/project/.npmrc".
verbose 0.649559572 Checking for configuration file "/home/user/.npmrc".
verbose 0.650454348 Checking for configuration file "/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.0/etc/npmrc".
verbose 0.651247908 Checking for configuration file "/home/user/vhtdocs/s/project/.npmrc".
verbose 0.6520772 Checking for configuration file "/home/user/vhtdocs/s/.npmrc".
verbose 0.653013165 Checking for configuration file "/home/user/vhtdocs/.npmrc".
verbose 0.654031989 Checking for configuration file "/home/user/.npmrc".
verbose 0.654781117 Checking for configuration file "/home/.npmrc".
verbose 0.65640441 Checking for configuration file "/home/user/vhtdocs/s/project/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.657429162 Checking for configuration file "/home/user/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.658158477 Found configuration file "/home/user/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.659509905 Checking for configuration file "/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.0/etc/yarnrc".
verbose 0.660365284 Checking for configuration file "/home/user/vhtdocs/s/project/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.661126718 Checking for configuration file "/home/user/vhtdocs/s/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.662244781 Checking for configuration file "/home/user/vhtdocs/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.663180621 Checking for configuration file "/home/user/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.664047646 Found configuration file "/home/user/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.679342779 Checking for configuration file "/home/.yarnrc".
verbose 0.693341934 current time: 2022-08-20T08:43:27.996Z
$ /home/user/vhtdocs/s/project/node_modules/.bin/encore dev --profile
Running webpack ...

 DONE  Compiled successfully in 60850ms                                                                                                                                                             08:44:34

135 files written to web/build/js

<--- Last few GCs --->

[21710:0x4a52810]   688427 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 1939.5 (1971.4) -> 1938.8 (1971.4) MB, 6465.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.079, current mu = 0.002) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[21710:0x4a52810]   694602 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 1939.8 (1968.4) -> 1938.9 (1969.7) MB, 6133.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.044, current mu = 0.007) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xa389b0 node::Abort() [webpack]
 2: 0x96e0af node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [webpack]
 3: 0xbb7a4e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [webpack]
 4: 0xbb7dc7 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [webpack]
 5: 0xd73fd5  [webpack]
 6: 0xd74b5f  [webpack]
 7: 0xd8299b v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [webpack]
 8: 0xd8655c v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [webpack]
 9: 0xd54c3b v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [webpack]
10: 0x109d21f v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [webpack]
11: 0x1446379  [webpack]
Aborted
verbose 701.761060613 Error: Command failed with exit code 134.
    at ProcessTermError.ExtendableBuiltin (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.0/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:721:66)
    at ProcessTermError.MessageError (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.0/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:750:123)
    at new ProcessTermError (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.0/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:790:113)
    at /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.0/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:34672:30
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at step (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.0/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:310:30)
    at /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.0/lib/node_modules/yarn/lib/cli.js:323:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
error Command failed with exit code 134.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Here's our `webpack.config.js` -- which I don't know a great deal about, unfortunately:

```js
const encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');

/**
 * CSS/SASS config
 */
encore
    .setOutputPath('web/build/css')
    .setPublicPath('/build/css')

    .addStyleEntry('add_to_basket', './assets/js/css-entrypoints/add_to_basket.js')
    .addStyleEntry('redirect_to_supplier_custom_booking_url', './assets/js/css-entrypoints/redirect_to_supplier_custom_booking_url.js')
    .addStyleEntry('legacy_add_to_basket', './assets/js/css-entrypoints/legacy_add_to_basket.js')
    .addStyleEntry('base', './assets/js/css-entrypoints/base.js')
    .addStyleEntry('hotel_book_now', './assets/js/css-entrypoints/hotel_book_now.js')
    .addStyleEntry('overseer_iframe', './assets/js/css-entrypoints/overseer_iframe.js')
    .addStyleEntry('overseer', './assets/js/css-entrypoints/overseer.js')
    .addStyleEntry('vendor_misc', './assets/js/css-entrypoints/vendor_misc.js')
    .addStyleEntry('email', './assets/js/css-entrypoints/email.js')
    .addStyleEntry('pdf', './assets/js/css-entrypoints/pdf.js')

    // Splits files into smaller pieces for greater optimization
    .splitEntryChunks()

    // Creates a single runtime.js file to be used on all pages, rather than including it in each bundle
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    // Enable hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning()

    .enableSourceMaps(!encore.isProduction())

    // enables SASS/SCSS support. Magic importer prevents files from being imported more than once
    .enableSassLoader()

    // We use PostCSS for auto-prefixing
    .enablePostCssLoader((options) => {
        if (options.postcssOptions === undefined) {
            options.postcssOptions = {};
        }

        options.postcssOptions.config = path.resolve(__dirname, 'postcss.config.js');
    })
;

const cssConfig = encore.getWebpackConfig();
cssConfig.name = 'css';

/**
 * JS Config
 */
encore.reset(); // Important - forget everything above!

encore
    .setOutputPath('web/build/js')
    .setPublicPath('/build/js')
    .autoProvidejQuery()
    .splitEntryChunks()
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .enableVersioning()
    // .enableSourceMaps(!encore.isProduction())
    // React is used for /book-now/.
    .enableReactPreset()
    // See https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2979#issuecomment-287675568
    .addPlugin(new webpack.IgnorePlugin({
        resourceRegExp: /\.\/locale$/,
        contextRegExp: /moment.*/,
    }))
;

var jsAssetsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'assets/js');

/**
 * Dynamically create entries, based on files in the entrypoints dir
 *
 * For a JS file assets/js/Bundle/Controller/action.entry.js, we
 * we end up with an entrypoint called Bundle/Controller/action
 */
glob
    // Get array of .entrypoint.js(x) files, including in sub-directories
    .sync('**/*.entry.+(js|jsx)', {cwd: jsAssetsPath})
    .forEach(relativeFilePath => {
        let relativeFilePathParts = path.parse(relativeFilePath);

        let entryPointName = path.join(
            relativeFilePathParts.dir,
            relativeFilePathParts.name.replace('.entry', '')
        );

        let fullFilePath = path.join(jsAssetsPath, relativeFilePath);

        encore.addEntry(entryPointName, fullFilePath);
    })
;

const jsConfig = encore.getWebpackConfig();
jsConfig.name = 'js';

// Ensure both node_modules and our AMD modules that haven't been moved over yet are available to Webpack
jsConfig.resolve.modules = ['assets/js/modules', 'node_modules'];

// Make sure Webpack knows browser globals are available
jsConfig.target = 'web';

// We have a downstream dependency which wants the 'fs' module in a web context.
// See https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/447
// jsConfig.node = { fs: 'empty' };

// @todo now we're off requireJS, gradually get rid of these aliases
jsConfig.resolve.alias = {
    "bower_components": path.join(__dirname, "web/bower_components"),
    "bundles": path.join(__dirname, "web/bundles"),

    //Module names:
    "jquery": "jquery/dist/jquery",
    "jquery.amaran": "AmaranJS/dist/js/jquery.amaran",
    "jquery.select2": "select2/dist/js/select2.full",
    "jquery.keepinsight": path.join(__dirname, "web/bower_components/jquery-keepinsight/jquery.keepinsight"),
    "jquery.backstretch": path.join(__dirname, "web/bower_components/jquery-backstretch/jquery.backstretch"),
    "jquery.zaccordion": "zAccordion/js/jquery.zaccordion",
    "jquery.fancybox": "fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox",
    "slickCarousel": "slick-carousel/slick/slick",
    "InfiniteAjaxScroll": "@webcreate/infinite-ajax-scroll/dist/infinite-ajax-scroll",
    "sweetAlert": "sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min",
    "momentJs": "moment/min/moment.min",
    "jquery.mmenu": "jquery.mmenu/dist/jquery.mmenu.all",
    "tooltipster": "tooltipster/dist/js/tooltipster.bundle",
    "jquery.worky": "myworld-frontend/js/jquery.worky",
    "window": "myworld-frontend/js/window",
    "MyWorld": "myworld-frontend/js/myworld",
    "MyWorld.Forms": "myworld-frontend/js/forms.js",
    "MyWorld.alerter": "myworld-frontend/js/alerter",
    "MyWorld.translator": "myworld-frontend/js/translator",
    "MyWorld.infiniteScroller": "myworld-frontend/js/infinite_scroller",
    "MyWorld.notifier": "myworld-frontend/js/notifier",
    "MyWorld.dateHelper": "myworld-frontend/js/date_helper",
    "MyWorld.layout": "myworld-frontend/js/layout",
    "MyWorld.dateTimePicker": "myworld-frontend/js/datetime_picker",
    "clipboard": path.join(__dirname, "web/bower_components/clipboard/dist/clipboard"),
    "autosize": path.join(__dirname, "web/bower_components/autosize/dist/autosize"),
};

module.exports = [cssConfig, jsConfig];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never really got to the bottom of this, but I do know that the script was blowing up in PostCSS, even without plugins enabled.  I *guess* the problem is simply we have a *lot* of Sass.

I ended-up increasing memory allocation to Node.js by setting the value of the `max_old_space_size` option.  Here's what our Webpack Encore dev build-script looks like now:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=3072 && yarn encore dev --progress
```

Earlier:

In answer to one of my own questions...  I just found out, entirely by accident, that it's possible to get more information about what Webpack is doing by specifying `stats` options in the/a config object exported from `webpack.config.js`.

```
stats: {
  errors: true,
  errorStack: true,
  errorDetails: true,
  children: true
}
```

Full details of the `stats` option here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/#statserrors